# excel error testing cells without error gives type mismatch (CVErr(xlErrNA))

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling

I'm starting to get the basics of VBA and I've wrote a macro which does the stuff I want (might not be the most elegant way but it works).

One of the things it does is write an excel formula to certain cells in column 8

```
"=VLOOKUP(RC[-6],TotalsPerClient!C9:C12,4,FALSE)"
```

This VLOOKUP is going to return some #N/A values and that's fine for me. Afterwards I like to go through the column and remove the errors. I first tried the following:

```
For i = 1 To LastRow
    If ws4.Cells(i, 8).Value = CVErr(xlErrNA) Then
        ws4.Cells(i, 8).ClearContents
    End If
Next i
```

However, I get a type mismatch. I understand now that since there is not a formula in every cell some cells do not give an error and hence a type mismatch. I've then used the following:

```
        If IsError(ws4.Cells(i, 8).Value) Then
            ws4.Cells(i, 8).ClearContents
        End If
```

Which works and does the trick.

For educational purposes; is there a way to use the `Cell.Value = CVErr(xlErrNA)` instead of my own solution? Using the `CVErr(xlErrNA)` seems a bit more specific and would narrow down the scope of what I'm deleting.

Comment: So which one is it, you think it's too narrow, or it's what you would like to be using?

Answer (score 2):

Usually the error happens the other way around: there's a `Variant/Error` value in some `Range.Value` that's being compared to a string or integer literal, and boom, type mismatch - because `Variant/Error` cannot be compared to anything other than a `Variant/Error`.

The inverse is also true, so the comparison explodes with a *type mismatch* all the same, whenever `ws4.Cells(i, 8).Value` does *not* contain an error:

```vb
If ws4.Cells(i, 8).Value = CVErr(xlErrNA) Then
```

The `IsError` function exists *specifically* to evaluate whether a `Variant` has the `Error` subtype. And once you know you're looking at a `Variant/Error`, then a comparison to another `Variant/Error` value is valid, because the types *match* now - so you can narrow `IsError` further down and handle specific cell errors differently as needed:

```
Dim Cell As Range
Set Cell = ws4.Cells(i, 8)

If IsError(Cell.Value) Then
    'Variant/Error comparisons are safe here.
    If Cell.Value = CVErr(xlErrNA) Then
        Cell.ClearContents
    Else
        'cell contains an error, but it's not #N/A.
    End If
Else
    'cell does not contain an error.
    'Variant/Error comparisons would throw a type mismatch here.
End If
```